# Remove duplicate elements by row in a data frame

Tags: r

I need to replace duplicate elements to NA by row from a data frame.  I will take base, `tidyverse` or `data.table` solutions.  Thank you.  Example:

```
library(tibble)
#input data.frame
tribble(
  ~x, ~y,  ~z,
  1,   2,   3,
  1,   1,   NA,
  4,   1,   4,
  2,   2,   3
)

#desired output
tribble(
  ~x, ~y,  ~z,
  1,   2,   3,
  1,   NA,   NA,
  4,   1,   NA,
  2,   3,   NA
)
```

Comment: Try `df1 %>% rowwise() %>% do(data.frame(replace(., duplicated(unlist(.)), NA)))`

Comment: surprisingly slower than the base solution.  With this one the `NA`s dont float to the end of the row.  I tried `df1 %>% rowwise() %>% do(data.frame(sort(replace(., duplicated(unlist(.)), NA),na.last=T)))` but I get an error Error in `sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
  'x' must be atomic`.

Comment: The `do` is a bit slower

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `base R` option where we loop through the rows, `replace` the `duplicated` elements with `NA` and concatenate (`c`) the non-NA elements with the `NA` elements, transpose (`t`) and assign the output back to the original dataset

```
df1[] <- t(apply(df1, 1, function(x) {
        x1 <- replace(x, duplicated(x), NA)
        c(x1[!is.na(x1)], x1[is.na(x1)])
        }))
df1
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#       x     y     z
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2     3
#2     1    NA    NA
#3     4     1    NA
#4     2     3    NA
```

Comment: Works much faster than the ugly for loop I wrote.  thanks!